# How to display webcam on client side only?

Tags: browser, client-side, webcam

I'd like to show a webcam inside a browser without any server interaction.

Everything should happen client side with minimal plugins usage.

This would replicate most default webcam software bundled with the cam itself.

Comment: Is it not possible with Flash?

Comment: Dunno, that's why i'm asking =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a plugin for each major browser (or an active x control for IE) to communicate locally with the phone. Because of security, you can not interact with local devices in a browser.

You could however write a little server that runs on localhost and serves a flash or mpeg stream. Then it would be easy to link that webcam to a web page running on the same computer. This would not require any plugins, but it does require that you write a http server to talk to the cam and serve its stream to the browser.

Comment: Updated answer: It is possible to save streams using HTML5 local storage now.